# datepickr popup opens outside of bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use datepickr (https://code.google.com/p/datepickr/) script within bootstrap tabs. My problem is that when i use the datepicker within the tab, the popup is open on the top-left position in the window, instead bellow of the field.

When used outside of the bootstrap tabs, works like a charm.

I am trying to solve this issue 10 hours now, without any luck.

Anyone can give me a hand with this?

Here are is  the css for the datepickr:

```
        .calendar {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            background-color: #EEE;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #777;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 14em;

        }

        .calendar .months {
            background-color: #58453F;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 0.2em;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .calendar .prev-month,
        .calendar .next-month {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .calendar .prev-month {
            float: left;
        }

        .calendar .next-month {
            float: right;
        }

        .calendar .current-month {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .calendar .months .prev-month,
        .calendar .months .next-month {
            color: #FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0 0.4em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .calendar .months .prev-month:hover,
        .calendar .months .next-month:hover {
            background-color: #FDF5CE;
            color: #C77405;
        }

        .calendar table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .calendar th {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .calendar td {
            text-align:center ;
            padding: 1px;
            width: 14.3%;
        }

        .calendar td span {
            display: block;
            color: #555;
            background-color: #F6F6F6;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0.2em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .calendar td span:hover {
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #58453F;
            border: 1px solid #58453F;
        }

        .calendar td.today span {
            background-color: #FFF0A5;
            border: 1px solid #FED22F;
            color: #363636;
        }
```

I am posting here portion of the javascript which cause the problem here, instead of whole file.

After investigating, i find out that when i use the datepicker outside of the tabs, the following variables have values, while when used within tabs, their values are 0,0 respectively.

```
 if(obj.offsetParent) {

     do {
    inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
    inputTop += obj.offsetTop;

        alert(inputLeft); // show alert with values when outside of tab, alert is not shown when within tab
        alert(inputTop); // show alert with values when outside of tab, alert is not shown when within tab

} while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
} 

var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top: ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';
....
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css: `.tab-content{position: relative}`. I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Could be two things. The this reference could be window insted the node object that you created. And if you have not appended this node to the dom, there is no chance that you could take the real offset of it.

Comment: And how can I test that? If true, how can I add that node to the dom?

Comment: You could use jQuery to make the node and append it to the tab. Or in pure javascript you could do the `element.appendChild(calendarContainer)`. Then select it again using the classname and do the maths.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help, I rally appreciate it. Any chance that you can send some code snippet?

Comment: It depends on what libraries you are using. Ehmmm... if you could make a fiddle or send me a zip with your code i could fix it. 

Another thing that you could do is add the element after the input and make the style position relative and do margin-top with negative values.